# Stream a song on an iphoe to another iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, client-server

Is it possible to write an iphone app that allows a user to pick a song (located on their iphone) and have it play out on an another iphone based on a client-server type relationship over a wifi connection?

Thanks for your help,

Lee

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever get access to song data from the iPod library on the phone. All you can do is get the phone to play the audio. Apple won't allow this as it would violate copyright.